# Joint Distribution of two correlated ito integral

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have a question regarding finding the joint distribution of two process$$dX_{t}=a_{t}dB_{t}$$$$dY_{t}=b_{t}dW_{t}$$where $B_{t}$ and $W_{t}$ are two Brownian motions with correlated increments, in which $Corr_{t}(dB_{t}, dW_{t}$)=$\rho$. 
My question is to find the joint distribution of ($X_{t}$, $Y_{t}$).

I know that both X and Y has normal distribution, but for correlated, how to proceed for finding the joint distribution, I am very confused now..

Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: So... you need two means, two variances and one correlation, right? Surely you are able to compute *some* of them!

Comment: thank you @Did. So for sure $(X_{t}, Y_{t})$ has a joint normal distribution with mean (0,0) and covariance matrix with diagonal $(1/2)\int_0^ta_{s}^2ds$ and $(1/2)\int_0^tb_{s}^2ds$. Lastly to find covariance, cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y). We know that E(X)=E(Y)=0 since X,Y martingale, but how to find E(XY) then

Comment: There is no 1/2 in the variances. To complete, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: One needs two means, two variances and one correlation. The OP already knows the value of the means and the variances. For the correlation, note that
$$
E[X_tY_t]=E\left[\int_0^ta_s\,\mathrm dB_s\cdot\int_0^tb_s\,\mathrm dW_s\right]=E\left[\int_0^ta_sb_s\,\mathrm d\langle B,W\rangle_s\right]
=\rho\cdot \int_0^tE\left[a_sb_s\right]\cdot\mathrm ds.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain more why $d⟨B,W⟩_{s}=\rho ds$? And I am assuming you used Fubini in the last equality?

Comment: I think I got it, thank you so much